# How to get property from API Response in Node JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, api, openweathermap

I have an API in node JS that calls another API - openWeatherMap.
This is my postman response when i call the weather API:
[image]

But this response brings every parameters in the API and I want to show the user for example the temp.min. How can I do this?

Comment: please share the part of the nodejs code that sends that payload after calling the other api

Comment: request({ url: url, json: true }, function (error, response) { 
                if (error) { 
                    console.log('Unable to connect to Forecast API'); 
                } 
                else { 
                    res.status(200).send(response.body.list[0].main.temp_min);
                } 
            })

Comment: before sending do a console log and see if the data is there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use 'Dot Notation' to access the required object property.
[Refer to the MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) or a resource like W3 for more information on how to use this.

In your case, you could declare a variable equal to the property you wish to access:

```
minTemp = response.body.list[0].main.temp_min
```

Answer (score 2):

you can access to json Object values with thier keys, for example:

```
response.body.list[0].main.temp_min
```

Comment: This does not work. It send an error saying: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')